# Are the VBAR_EL registers saved over context switch in ARM?

Tags: linux, arm, cpu-registers, armv8

I was told at one point that the VBAR_EL0/1 registers are not backed up on a context switch.  I also noticed that the VBAR_EL0/1 registers are not listed [here](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/a-profile/docs/den0024/latest/the-memory-management-unit/context-switching), but outside of that I'm not finding much information on it.  Does this mean that the exception table has to be at the same place for all 32 bit processes?   Also, how does this work when switching between 32 and 64 bit processor modes?

I'm using Linux 4.1 cross compiled for Armv8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question about context switch, I do not find any existing reference but my personal experience is that all processes share the same exception vector table unless you manually update the VBAR_EL0/1 register. 
If you update the registers successfully, then all processes will find the exception handler based on the new register's value.

For your second question:

> how does this work when switching between 32 and 64 bit processor modes?

According to the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](http://mazsola.iit.uni-miskolc.hu/~drdani/docs_arm/DDI0487A_e_armv8_arm.pdf):

> VBAR_EL1[31:0] is architecturally mapped to AArch32 System register VBAR.